# Introducing the third spatial dimension (Z-coordinate) in the generalized dissimilarity model in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, computational-statistics

Generalized dissimilarity modeling (R package gdm) is a tool to study the relative effects of the user-defined environmental gradients and the spatial distance decay on the pair-wise dissimilarity between samples (e.g. vegetation assemblages). The spatial distance in such models is *by default* expressed by a euclidean distance based on the geographical position of plots in a two-dimensional space.

I am interested, though, whether apart from the geographical coordinates a 3rd dimension, let it be elevation, can be introduced in the model? Do you have an idea of how to achieve it within the framework of this package?